# Maze player model view and controller

Tags: c++, game, mvc

This is the player view model and controller for human player using a keyboard (easily extendable for over the network / split screen mode).

The AI controller is posted in another post I've made earlier.

**mazePlayerModel.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include "CMaze.h"

namespace amazeinggame
{

    struct CPlayerInnerData;

    class CMazePlayerControllerInterface;
    class CMazePlayerHumanController;

    struct CMazePlayerState
    {
        float x, y, speedX, speedY, currentAngle, angularSpeed, remainingAngle;
    };

    class CMazePlayerModel
    {
    public:
        CMazePlayerModel();
        CMazePlayerModel(const CMazePlayerModel &) = delete;
        CMazePlayerModel(CMazePlayerModel &&);
        ~CMazePlayerModel();
        void setDirection(maze::Direction in_newDirection);
        void stop();
        void evolve(float deltaT);
        void init(int in_mazePositionX, int in_mazePositionY, const maze::CMaze & in_maze,
            std::unique_ptr<CMazePlayerControllerInterface> in_controller);
        void setPlayerMovementSpeed(float in_speed);
        CMazePlayerHumanController * const getMazePlayerHumanController() const;
        CMazePlayerState getPlayerState() const;
        void setPlayerName(std::string in_playerName); 
        const std::string & getPlayerName() const;
    private:
        bool isAboutToCollide();
        void moveStraight(float deltaT);
        void turn(float deltaT);
        bool checkAndUseMovementQueue();
        std::unique_ptr<CPlayerInnerData> _pInnerData; //this is the place to hide the implementation details, so we don't have to include irrlicht from the header.
        std::unique_ptr<CMazePlayerControllerInterface> _controller;
        const maze::CMaze * _maze = nullptr; //there can be no maze player without a maze...
        std::string _name;
    };

}
```

**mazePlayerModel.cpp**

```
#include "MazePlayerModel.h"
#include "vector2d.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include "CMaze.h"
#include "MazePlayerControllerInterface.h"
#include "MazePlayerHumanController.h"

namespace amazeinggame
{

    enum class MovementState { MoveStraight, Rotate };

    struct CPlayerInnerData
    {
        CPlayerInnerData()  { }
        irr::core::vector2df currentPosition;
        irr::core::vector2df currentDirection = irr::core::vector2df(0, 1);
        irr::core::vector2df previousDirection = irr::core::vector2df(0, 1);
        float distanceToStopBeforeWall = 0.1;
        MovementState movementState = MovementState::MoveStraight;
        float currentSpeed = 0;
        float typicalSpeed = 5;
        float angularSpeed = 720;
        maze::Direction movementDirection = maze::Direction::North;
        float remainingAngle = 0;
        float currentAngle = 0;
        bool isStopRequested = false;
        float distanceWalkedFromLastTurn = 0;
        std::deque<maze::Direction> movementQueue;
    };




    CMazePlayerModel::CMazePlayerModel()
    {
        _pInnerData.reset(new CPlayerInnerData());

    }

    void CMazePlayerModel::init(int in_x, int in_y, const maze::CMaze & in_maze, 
        std::unique_ptr<CMazePlayerControllerInterface> in_controller)
    {
        _pInnerData->currentPosition = irr::core::vector2df(in_x, in_y);
        _maze = &in_maze;
        _controller = std::move(in_controller);
    }

    void CMazePlayerModel::setPlayerMovementSpeed(float in_speed)
    {
        _pInnerData->typicalSpeed = in_speed;
    }

    CMazePlayerModel::CMazePlayerModel(CMazePlayerModel &&other)
    {
        _pInnerData = std::move(other._pInnerData);
        _name = std::move(other._name);
        _maze = std::move(other._maze);
    }

    CMazePlayerModel::~CMazePlayerModel()
    {
    }


    void CMazePlayerModel::setDirection(maze::Direction in_newDirection)
    {
        if (_pInnerData->movementDirection != in_newDirection)
        {
            if (_pInnerData->currentSpeed > 0)
            { //if we're already moving, complete the move - and only than change direction.
                if (_pInnerData->movementQueue.size() > 2) //forget about earlier movement requests - the player has changed his mind.
                    _pInnerData->movementQueue.pop_front();
                _pInnerData->movementQueue.push_back(in_newDirection);
                return;
            }
            _pInnerData->previousDirection = _pInnerData->currentDirection;
            _pInnerData->movementDirection = in_newDirection;
            auto tempVectorDir = maze::getVectorFromDirection(_pInnerData->movementDirection);
            _pInnerData->currentDirection = irr::core::vector2df(tempVectorDir.first, tempVectorDir.second);

            irr::core::vector2df directionChange = _pInnerData->currentDirection - _pInnerData->previousDirection;
            if (1 < abs(directionChange.X) || 1 < abs(directionChange.Y))
                _pInnerData->remainingAngle = static_cast<int>(round(180 + _pInnerData->remainingAngle)) % 360;
            else if (irr::core::vector2df(_pInnerData->previousDirection.Y, -_pInnerData->previousDirection.X)
                .dotProduct(_pInnerData->currentDirection) < 0)
                _pInnerData->remainingAngle = static_cast<int>(round(_pInnerData->remainingAngle - 90)) % 360;
            else
                _pInnerData->remainingAngle = static_cast<int>(round(_pInnerData->remainingAngle + 90)) % 360;
            _pInnerData->movementState = MovementState::Rotate;
        }
        else
        {
            _pInnerData->movementState = MovementState::MoveStraight;
        }
        _pInnerData->currentSpeed = _pInnerData->typicalSpeed;
        _pInnerData->isStopRequested = false;
    }
    void CMazePlayerModel::evolve(float deltaT)
    {
        _controller->update(this);
        if (0 == _pInnerData->currentSpeed)
        {
            if (!checkAndUseMovementQueue())
                return;
        }
        if (_pInnerData->movementState == MovementState::Rotate)
            turn(deltaT);
        else
            moveStraight(deltaT);


    }

    void CMazePlayerModel::turn(float deltaT)
    {
        float rotationAngle;
        if (abs(_pInnerData->remainingAngle) < _pInnerData->angularSpeed * deltaT)
        {
            rotationAngle = _pInnerData->remainingAngle;
            _pInnerData->movementState = MovementState::MoveStraight;
            _pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn = 0;
        }
        else
            rotationAngle = _pInnerData->remainingAngle > 0 ? _pInnerData->angularSpeed * deltaT : -_pInnerData->angularSpeed * deltaT;
        _pInnerData->remainingAngle -= rotationAngle;
        _pInnerData->currentAngle += rotationAngle;
        //_pInnerData->playerSceneNode->setRotation(irr::core::vector3df(0, _pInnerData->playerSceneNode->getRotation().Y + rotationAngle, 0));
    }

    void CMazePlayerModel::moveStraight(float deltaT)
    {
        float stepSize = deltaT * _pInnerData->currentSpeed;
        if (stepSize > 1)
            stepSize = 1;
        irr::core::vector2df movementVector = _pInnerData->currentDirection * stepSize;
        bool shouldStop = false;
        float newDistanceFromLastTurn = _pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn + stepSize;
        float newDistanceFromCellCenterEdge = newDistanceFromLastTurn - std::ceil(_pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn);
        float newDistanceFromCellWall = newDistanceFromLastTurn - std::ceil(_pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn - _pInnerData->distanceToStopBeforeWall);
        if ((newDistanceFromCellWall >= 0) && isAboutToCollide())
        { //going to collide with wall
            movementVector = movementVector.normalize() * (std::ceil(_pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn - _pInnerData->distanceToStopBeforeWall) - _pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn);
            shouldStop = true;
            _pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn = 0;
        }
        else if ((newDistanceFromLastTurn > 1) && _pInnerData->isStopRequested && (newDistanceFromCellCenterEdge >= 0))
        { //if there are turns waiting to be taken, we can take them at this point
            movementVector = movementVector.normalize() * (std::ceil(_pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn) - _pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn);
            shouldStop = true;
            _pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn = 0;
        }
        else
            _pInnerData->distanceWalkedFromLastTurn = newDistanceFromLastTurn;
        //_pInnerData->playerSceneNode->setPosition(_pInnerData->playerSceneNode->getPosition() + movementVector);
        _pInnerData->currentPosition += movementVector;
        if (shouldStop) //this is here to make sure the walking animation continues up untill the last frame.
        {
            _pInnerData->currentSpeed = 0;
            checkAndUseMovementQueue();
        }
    }

    void CMazePlayerModel::stop()
    {
        _pInnerData->isStopRequested = true;
    }

    bool CMazePlayerModel::isAboutToCollide()
    {
        //This was the "physical" way to check for collisions - it's way slower than the new way...
        /*irr::core::vector3df collisionPoint;
        irr::core::triangle3df collisionTriangle;
        irr::scene::ISceneNode * collisionNode;
        bool collisionResult = _pInnerData->sceneManager->getSceneCollisionManager()->getCollisionPoint(
        irr::core::line3df(_pInnerData->playerSceneNode->getAbsolutePosition(),
        _pInnerData->playerSceneNode->getAbsolutePosition() +
        0.2 * _pInnerData->playerSceneNode->getBoundingBox().MinEdge.getLength() * _pInnerData->currentDirection),
        _pInnerData->levelTriangleSelector, collisionPoint, collisionTriangle, collisionNode);*/
        if (_maze)
            return !(_maze->isDirectionAllowedFromPosition(std::round(_pInnerData->currentPosition.X),
            std::round(_pInnerData->currentPosition.Y), _pInnerData->movementDirection));
        else
            return false; //if there is no maze... we can go everywhere!!!
    }

    bool CMazePlayerModel::checkAndUseMovementQueue()
    {
        if (_pInnerData->movementQueue.size())
        {
            setDirection(_pInnerData->movementQueue.front());
            _pInnerData->movementQueue.pop_front();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    CMazePlayerState CMazePlayerModel::getPlayerState() const
    {
        //x, y, speedX, speedY, currentAngle, angularSpeed, remainingAngle;
        return CMazePlayerState{ _pInnerData->currentPosition.X, _pInnerData->currentPosition.Y
            , _pInnerData->currentSpeed * _pInnerData->currentDirection.X
            , _pInnerData->currentSpeed * _pInnerData->currentDirection.Y,
            _pInnerData->currentAngle, _pInnerData->angularSpeed, _pInnerData->remainingAngle };
    }

    CMazePlayerHumanController * const CMazePlayerModel::getMazePlayerHumanController() const
    {
        return dynamic_cast<CMazePlayerHumanController *>(_controller.get());
    }

    void CMazePlayerModel::setPlayerName(std::string in_playerName)
    {
        _name = in_playerName;
    }
    const std::string & CMazePlayerModel::getPlayerName() const
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

**MazePlayerView.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace irr {
    namespace scene {
        class ISceneManager;
        class ICameraSceneNode;
        class IAnimatedMeshSceneNode;
        class ISceneNode;
    }
    namespace video
    {
        class ITexture;
    }
}

namespace amazeinggame
{

    class CMazePlayerModel;

    class CMazePlayerView
    {
    public:
        CMazePlayerView(CMazePlayerModel * const in_mazePlayer);
        CMazePlayerView();
        ~CMazePlayerView();
        void update(float in_RatioOfNextToPreviousTick);
        irr::scene::IAnimatedMeshSceneNode * addSceneNode(const CMazePlayerModel & in_mazePlayer, irr::scene::ISceneManager * const in_sceneManager, irr::scene::ISceneNode * const parentSceneNode);
        const irr::scene::IAnimatedMeshSceneNode * getSceneNode() const;
        void possesCamera(irr::scene::ICameraSceneNode * const in_camera);
        void setTexture(irr::video::ITexture * in_texture);
    private:
        void startWalkAnimation();
        void startIdleAnimation();
        void startRotationAnimation();
        void adjustCamera();
        static void setCurrentCameraPossesor(CMazePlayerView * in_possesor, irr::scene::ICameraSceneNode * const in_camera);
        const CMazePlayerModel * _playerModel = nullptr;
        irr::scene::IAnimatedMeshSceneNode * _playerSceneNode = nullptr;
        irr::scene::ICameraSceneNode * _camera = nullptr;
        enum class CurrentAnimationState { Walking, Rotating, Idle, NotSet } _currentAnimation = CurrentAnimationState::NotSet;
    };

}
```

**MazePlayerView.cpp**

```
#include "MazePlayerView.h"
#include "MazePlayerModel.h"
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace amazeinggame
{


CMazePlayerView::CMazePlayerView()
{
}


CMazePlayerView::~CMazePlayerView()
{
}



CMazePlayerView::CMazePlayerView(CMazePlayerModel * const in_mazePlayer)
    : _playerModel(in_mazePlayer)
{
}

void CMazePlayerView::setCurrentCameraPossesor(CMazePlayerView * in_possesor, irr::scene::ICameraSceneNode * const in_camera)
{
    static CMazePlayerView * currentCameraPossesor(nullptr);
    if (currentCameraPossesor != nullptr && currentCameraPossesor != in_possesor)
        currentCameraPossesor->_camera = nullptr;
    currentCameraPossesor = in_possesor;
    if (currentCameraPossesor)
        currentCameraPossesor->_camera = in_camera;
}


void CMazePlayerView::possesCamera(irr::scene::ICameraSceneNode * const in_camera)
{
    if (in_camera)
    {
        CMazePlayerView::setCurrentCameraPossesor(this, in_camera);
        adjustCamera();
    }
    else
        CMazePlayerView::setCurrentCameraPossesor(nullptr,nullptr);
}

void CMazePlayerView::adjustCamera()
{
    if (!_camera)
        return;
    _camera->setPosition(_playerSceneNode->getAbsolutePosition() + irr::core::vector3df(0, 5, -2));
    _camera->setUpVector(irr::core::vector3df(0, 0, 1));
    _camera->setTarget(_playerSceneNode->getAbsolutePosition());

}


void CMazePlayerView::startWalkAnimation()
{
    if (CurrentAnimationState::Walking == _currentAnimation)
        return;
    _currentAnimation = CurrentAnimationState::Walking;
    _playerSceneNode->setFrameLoop(0, 13);
}
void CMazePlayerView::startIdleAnimation()
{
    if (CurrentAnimationState::Idle == _currentAnimation)
        return;
    _currentAnimation = CurrentAnimationState::Idle;
    _playerSceneNode->setFrameLoop(205, 249);
}
void CMazePlayerView::startRotationAnimation()
{
    if (CurrentAnimationState::Rotating == _currentAnimation)
        return;
    _currentAnimation = CurrentAnimationState::Rotating;
    _playerSceneNode->setFrameLoop(133, 144);
}



irr::scene::IAnimatedMeshSceneNode * CMazePlayerView::addSceneNode(const CMazePlayerModel & in_mazePlayer, irr::scene::ISceneManager * const in_sceneManager, irr::scene::ISceneNode * const in_parent)
{
    _playerModel = &in_mazePlayer;
    irr::scene::IAnimatedMesh * ninjaMesh = in_sceneManager->getMesh("../media/ninja.b3d");
    auto playerState = _playerModel->getPlayerState();
    _playerSceneNode = in_sceneManager->addAnimatedMeshSceneNode(ninjaMesh, in_parent, -1, 
        irr::core::vector3df(playerState.x - 0.5, 0, playerState.y - 0.5),
        irr::core::vector3df(), irr::core::vector3df(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
    return _playerSceneNode;
}


void CMazePlayerView::update(float in_deltaT)
{
    auto playerState = _playerModel->getPlayerState();
    _playerSceneNode->setPosition(irr::core::vector3df(playerState.x - 0.5, 0, playerState.y - 0.5)
        + irr::core::vector3df(playerState.speedX, 0, playerState.speedY) * in_deltaT);
    _playerSceneNode->setRotation(irr::core::vector3df(0,
        playerState.currentAngle + std::min(playerState.angularSpeed * in_deltaT, playerState.remainingAngle), 0));
    if (playerState.speedX != 0 || playerState.speedY != 0)
    {
        startWalkAnimation();
        adjustCamera();
    }
    else
    {
        startIdleAnimation();
    }
}

void CMazePlayerView::setTexture(irr::video::ITexture * in_texture)
{
    _playerSceneNode->getMaterial(0).setTexture(0, in_texture);
}

const irr::scene::IAnimatedMeshSceneNode * CMazePlayerView::getSceneNode() const
{
    return _playerSceneNode;
}

}
```

**MazePlayerControllerInterface.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace amazeinggame
{
    class CMazePlayerModel;

    class CMazePlayerControllerInterface
    {
    public:
        virtual void update(CMazePlayerModel * const in_playerModel) = 0;
        CMazePlayerControllerInterface();
        virtual ~CMazePlayerControllerInterface();
    };
}
```

**MazePlayerHumanController.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "MazePlayerControllerInterface.h"
#include "CMaze.h"

namespace amazeinggame
{

    class CMazePlayerHumanController :
        public CMazePlayerControllerInterface
    {
    public:
        void update(CMazePlayerModel * const in_playerModel) final;
        void setDirection(maze::Direction in_direction);
        void stop();
        CMazePlayerHumanController();
        virtual ~CMazePlayerHumanController();
    private:
        bool _isStopRequested = true;
        bool _isSetDirectionRequested = false;
        maze::Direction _direction;
    };
}
```

**MazePlayerHumanController.cpp**

```
#include "MazePlayerHumanController.h"
#include "MazePlayerModel.h"

namespace amazeinggame
{
    CMazePlayerHumanController::CMazePlayerHumanController()
    {
    }


    CMazePlayerHumanController::~CMazePlayerHumanController()
    {
    }

    void CMazePlayerHumanController::update(CMazePlayerModel * in_playerModel)
    {
        if (_isStopRequested)
        {
            in_playerModel->stop();
            _isStopRequested = false;
            return;
        }
        if (_isSetDirectionRequested)
        {
            in_playerModel->setDirection(_direction);
            _isSetDirectionRequested = false;
        }
    }

    void CMazePlayerHumanController::setDirection(maze::Direction in_direction)
    {
        _direction = in_direction;
        _isSetDirectionRequested = true;
    }
    void CMazePlayerHumanController::stop()
    {
        _isStopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

**MazeGameEventReciever.cpp**

```
#include "MazeGameEventReciever.h"
#include "MazeGameEngine.h"
#include "MazePlayerHumanController.h"
#include "irrlicht.h"

namespace amazeinggame
{


CMazeGameEventReciever::CMazeGameEventReciever(CMazeGameEngine * const in_gameEngine)
        : _parentGameEngine(in_gameEngine)
{

}


CMazeGameEventReciever::~CMazeGameEventReciever()
{
}

void CMazeGameEventReciever::setPlayerController(CMazePlayerHumanController * const in_playerController)
{
    _playerController = in_playerController;
}

bool CMazeGameEventReciever::OnEvent(const irr::SEvent& event)
{
    if (event.EventType == irr::EET_KEY_INPUT_EVENT)
    {
        switch (event.KeyInput.Key)
        {
        case irr::EKEY_CODE::KEY_UP: if (event.KeyInput.PressedDown) {
            _playerController->setDirection(maze::Direction::North);
        }
                                     else
                                         _playerController->stop(); break;
        case irr::EKEY_CODE::KEY_DOWN: if (event.KeyInput.PressedDown) {
            _playerController->setDirection(maze::Direction::South);
        }
                                       else
                                           _playerController->stop(); break;
        case irr::EKEY_CODE::KEY_LEFT: if (event.KeyInput.PressedDown) {
            _playerController->setDirection(maze::Direction::West);
        }
                                       else
                                           _playerController->stop(); break;
        case irr::EKEY_CODE::KEY_RIGHT: if (event.KeyInput.PressedDown) {
            _playerController->setDirection(maze::Direction::East);
        }
                                        else
                                            _playerController->stop(); break;
        case irr::EKEY_CODE::KEY_ESCAPE: if (event.KeyInput.PressedDown) _parentGameEngine->showMenu();
        default: return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to go through. I suggest you break it up into your model class for one question, your view for another, and your controller for the third, and then provide actual links to each question from the others. Also, if you want people to check out your AI controller, post the link, don't just say it exists and expect people to hunt it down. Once you've done that, explain what you want out of this code review. Are you looking for performance advice? Architecture? Best-practices? Algorithm advice? Something else?